# ModelState.IsValid returns true if destinationId is set to 0 via javascript else false

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public class InventoryEventViewModel{
      public int DestinationId { get; set; }
      public int EventType { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Save(InventoryEventViewModel viewModel)
 {
           //added a breakpoint here

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
             //do something
             }
}
```

in razor view

```
<select name="DestinationId" id="DestinationId">
<option>Select Destination</option>
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

`$('#DestinationId').val(@Model.DestinationId)` -> returns 0

DestinationId is of type int so its default value is 0, when I submit the form I added a breakpoint just below the ActionResult line to view viewModel content and I found that viewModel.DestinationId is 0 thus `ModelState.IsValid` returns `true`. However if i remove this line `$('#DestinationId').val(@Model.DestinationId)`, `$('#DestinationId')` will then have a default value of blank but in my breakpoint viewModel.DestinationId is still 0 but `ModelState.IsValid` returns `false`, I'm starting to think that `ModelState` doesn't actualy refers to the state of `viewModel`. Then what is the relationship between the two?

Comment: Its not clear what you asking. If you post a name/vale pair for `DestinationId` and the value is not a valid `int`(for example you have selected the first option which has a value of "Select Destination"), then `ModelState` will be invalid because the value you posted is invalid and cannot be set to an `int`, so `DestinationId` will have its default value.

Comment: It was my impression that ModelState actually refers to viewModel, that it validates its values but it seems this is not the case. And that even if I've posted a blank DestinationId but later below ActionResult I fix it with `viewModel.DestinationId = 0;` it will then be valid

Comment: Yes, but it takes into account the values that you are attempting to set from the request. If you submit say 1, its valid because it can be converted to an `int`. For you omit anything from the request, or submit something that is not a valid value, `ModelState` will be invalid,but the actual value will be its default.

Comment: Change the first option to `<option value="">Select Destination</option>` and hopefully that should give you your desired output.

Comment: @StephenMuecke is there a way to make ModelState return true after it's been submitted? viewModel.DestinationId has already been set to 0 (default) before ModelState.IsValid gets called. I was expecting ModelState.IsValid will return true at that time since viewModel.DestinationId is 0

Comment: If you submit a value which is not valid for an `int`, then `ModelState` will be invalid (that's by design, and as it should be). Its not clear why you would expect it to be valid

Comment: @Shyju, That will still result in `ModelState` being invalid because the property is not nullable (although your correct in that it should have `value=""`)

Comment: Yes. So when user selects the first option("Select Destination"), it should cause the ModelState to fail. I guess that is what OP wanted ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke there's another field thats inplay, I want DestinationId to be valid even if it's blank if `EventType == 2` but will be invalid if `EventType == 1`

Comment: There is nothing in your question about that :). But if you want some kind of conditional validation, then you would use a conditional validation attribute applied to your `DestinationId` property (and make it nullable) - for example `[RequiredIfNot("EventType", 2)]public int? DestinationId { get; set; }`

Comment: And of course you would generate you view correctly using the strong typed `HtmlHelper` methods (`@Html.DropDownListFor()` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`) so that you get client and server side validation

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke I'll research on that conditional validation :)

Comment: You can use a library such as [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof), or if you want to learn to write you own, start with [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)